# How can I optimise this simple piece of code

Tags: c#, performance

This code draws a number of cubes on the screen selected from an array in one of three colours. How can I make it more efficient?

```
    void DrawMap(){
    levelParent=new GameObject();
    levelParent.name="Level";
    for (int x=1;x<complexity-1;x++){
        for (int y=1;y<complexity-1;y++){
            GameObject go;
            go = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
            go.name="Ground "+x+y;
            go.transform.parent=levelParent.transform;

            switch (finallayer[x,y]){
            case 0:
                //go = (GameObject) Instantiate(brick, new Vector3(-complexity/2+x+.5f, 0 , -complexity/2+y+.5f), Quaternion.identity);
                go.transform.position= new Vector3(-complexity/2+x+screenOffsetX, 0 , -complexity/2+y+screenOffsetZ);
                go.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color=Color.green;
                break;
            case 1:
                go.transform.position= new Vector3(-complexity/2+x+screenOffsetX,.5f, -complexity/2+y+screenOffsetZ);
                go.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color=Color.grey;          
                break;
            case 2:
                go.transform.position= new Vector3(-complexity/2+x+screenOffsetX,1f, -complexity/2+y+screenOffsetZ);
                go.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color=Color.black;
                break;
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: The desire to improve code is implied for all questions on this site. Question titles should reflect the purpose of the code, not how you wish to have it reworked. See [ask].

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a possibilty to make your code more performant, but I see a few ways how you could improve the readability of the code.

- variables and values really love to have some space to breath. If you deny them that space, maybe they get depressed but for sure they get almost unreadable.
- variablenames which are compound words like `final layer` should be named using `camelCase` casing, so `finallayer[x,y]` should become `finalLayer[x,y]`.
- commented out code is dead code and decreases readability by adding noise to the real code. Dead code should be deleted because it doesn't have any value anymore. To keep track of code changes one should use a source control system like subversion or git etc.
- related section of code will be more prominent and better readable if separated by vertical space (new lines)

---

> ```
> go.name="Ground "+x+y;
> ```

what have the game objects with the coordinates

1. `x == 1`, `y == 12`
2. `x == 11`, `y == 2`

in common ? Its the name which really should not happen. By adding a separator like a `,` between `x` and `y` makes the name unique which will help if you need to query the game object by name.

So either use `string.format` like so

```
go.name = string.Format("Ground {0},{1}", x, y);
```

or if you are using C# 6.0 you can use stringinterpolation like so

```
go.name = $"Ground {x},{y}";
```

---

The "default" rule for placing opening braces `{` in C# is onto the next line. If you have choosen to use the java like style thats ok, but for the usual C# developer it just looks wierd. Having an own style isn't bad as long as you stick to it.

---

The only difference between the positions of these 3 different game objects is the second parameter which can be easily calculated by converting the `finalLayer[x,y]` to a float like so

```
float secondParameter = (float)finalLayer[x,y] / 2f;
```

at least if the values of `finalLayer` are in the range [0,1,2]

---

By having an array of color like

```
Color[] colors = new Color[] { Color.green, Color.grey, Color.black };
```

and using the said calculation of the second parameter we can get rid of the `swicth..case` statement.

---

Applying the mentioned points will lead to

```
void DrawMap()
{
    levelParent = new GameObject();
    levelParent.name = "Level";

    for (int x = 1; x < complexity - 1; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 1; y < complexity - 1; y++)
        {

            float secondParameter = (float)finalLayer[x, y] / 2;

            GameObject go = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
            go.name = $"Ground {0},{1}";
            go.transform.parent = levelParent.transform;
            go.transform.position = new Vector3(-complexity / 2 + x + screenOffsetX, secondParameter, -complexity / 2 + y + screenOffsetZ);
            go.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = colors[finalLayer[x, y]];
        }
    }
}
```

Taking into account the comment of [`@DavidArno`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31189/david-arno)

> One more readability improvement you could make is to replace int x, float secondParameter etc with var's

If the right hand side of an assignment to a variable one can use `var` instead of the concrete type of the variable like so

```
void DrawMap()
{
    levelParent = new GameObject();
    levelParent.name = "Level";

    for (var x = 1; x < complexity - 1; x++)
    {
        for (var y = 1; y < complexity - 1; y++)
        {

            var secondParameter = (float)finalLayer[x, y] / 2;

            GameObject go = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
            go.name = $"Ground {0},{1}";
            go.transform.parent = levelParent.transform;
            go.transform.position = new Vector3(-complexity / 2 + x + screenOffsetX, secondParameter, -complexity / 2 + y + screenOffsetZ);
            go.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = colors[finalLayer[x, y]];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One more readability improvement you could make is to replace `int x`, `float secondParameter` etc with `var`'s.

Comment: @DavidArno I like to have the concrete type, nevertheless your comment is valid and I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Heslacher : Being from a 90's C++ background I've never understood why people think code is more readable when the types aren't defined.  I understand I'm wrong, but why are vars better?

Comment: @Matt I didn't say vars are better, but they can help under certain circumstances. Assume you change a method argument from `int` to `long` which is called in a normal `for` loop with the loop iteration variable as parameter. If you have used `int i = 0` instead of `var i = 0` you would need to change the `int` to `long`. I form myself use `var` seldom because I like to see at first glance of what type a variable is.